# \chapter and \section change the appearence of text

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I want to create a table of contents for my book. Therefore I put some chapters and sections into the text with \chapter and \section commands. That causes changes the display of the text. Is there a way for no changes into the original form and work ToC as well?

Edit: I'm looking for two things: 1. To have different names of chapters into the text and the contents. 2. The \chapter and \section commands not to change the original form of the text. Just to stay exactly as it appears in the first code that I posted.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{center}
\begin{Large}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colbacktitle=red,colback=white!80!black , text width=10cm, title=\begin{center}
Chapter 1
\end{center}] \begin{LARGE}\begin{center}
\textbf{ Section 1.1 }
\end{center}
\end{LARGE}\end{tcolorbox}
\end{Large}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\begin{Large}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colbacktitle=red,colback=white!80!black , text width=10cm, title=\begin{center}   
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\end{center}] \begin{LARGE}\begin{center}
\section{\textbf{ Section 1.1 }}
\end{center}
\end{LARGE}\end{tcolorbox}
\end{Large}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, its not fully clear what you want to achieve; *what* causes *which* specific changes? You don't need to count chapter and sections manually, Latex takes care of it. And to change the appearance of e.g. the font, you should not use commands like `\section{\textbf{ Section 1.1 }}`. There are packages which can handle it as well as editing counters etc. like `tocloft`, `tocstyle` or `titletoc`.

Comment: @lukeflo I'm looking for two things: 1. To have different names of chapters into the text and the contents. 2. The \chapter and \section commands not to change the original form of the text. Just to stay exactly as the first code that I posted (sorry for my bad english).

Comment: No problem. But its still not clear to me. Just edit your post and show, what you want as plain output without any TeX code mixed in.

Comment: I take you are formatting the chapter and section titles directly.  You can use `\addcontentsline` to add titles to the TOC.  This is commonly done with `\section*` and `\chapter*` (many examples on this site).  Chapter and section numbers are handled by `\numberline`.

Comment: @lukeflo and John Kormylo thank you both. Actually \addcontentsline was the solution to the main problem and tocloft for the rest!

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're wanting to do.  Generally, you shouldn't put "Section" or the number in a `\section` command but leave that to LaTeX.  The only thing that should go into the `\section` command is the title of the section, which you haven't shown us (unless you're titling it "Section 1.1" after all, in which case, just use `\section{}`).  Then you would use secsty or titlesec to style the headings.

Comment: @Teepeemm I don't want to have the words "chapter" or "section" into the text. If I have, for example, a chapter named "Math Functions" and write \chapter{"Math Functions"} it 'll show "Chapter 1:Math Functions", but I only want "Math Functions" to seem. So I just use \addcontentsline in order to create toc.

Answer (score 0):

According to the discussion:

Actually `\addcontentsline` was the solution to the main problem and `tocloft` for the rest!